# QTreeview : How to change the defalut position of the text item

Tags: qt

Could you please let me know how to chage the position of the item in QTreeView.By default the item displayed at Left most and in the center of the item box.But how should i change it so that it will display in top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using a Qt built-in item model**

If you are using e.g. `QFileSystemModel` you have to inherit from it and override the `data()` behaviour:

```
class MyFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel {
public:
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
    if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
      return Qt::AlignTop; //maybe different result depending on column/row
    else
      return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
  }
```

and then use that class instead.

**Using own item model**

If you implemented your own item model all you have to do is handle `Qt::TextAlignmentRole` in `data()`:

```
QVariant MyTreeModel::data (const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
  if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
    return Qt::AlignTop; //maybe different result depending on column/row

  //handle other roles

  return QVariant();
}
```

The tree view should now automatically align the items to the top.

If you want to customize the appearance even further, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) are the roles that are used by `QTreeView`. For more customization I think you have to implement your own `QTreeView` subclass.

**Using QStandardItemModel**

If you did not implement your own model but used `QStandardItemModel` you have to call
`setTextAlignment(Qt::Alignment alignment)` with `Qt::AlignTop` on your standard items before adding them to the model.

Comment: I have to use on QTreeView and let me see i can implement QItemDelegate.

Comment: All these solutions imply that you are using a QTreeView to display the data. You just have to call view->setModel(myModel) to get your data displayed at the top. Unless what you really are trying to achieve is having an edit widget aligned to the top you probably don't need a custom QItemDelegate.